# Namespace result in xsl:result-document appears on children instead of parent element

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I, like many, am having trouble understanding how to control some xslt namespace declarations in xslt ouput. I'm using a recent version of Saxon XSLT 2.0 processor in Java. I'be been able to find solutions to most of the issues I was having with `<xsl:output>` namespace declarations, but I'm having trouble with a `<xsl:result-document>` namespace declaration. I'm using XSL to create portions of epub3 files.

Following is the pertinent part of my **XSLT** 2.0 file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:my="my:functions" 
exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsl dc epub my"
version="2.0">
<xsl:output name="xhtml" method="xhtml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:output name="xml" method="xml" indent="no"/>
<!--content.opf -->
<xsl:result-document href="{concat('ePubs/ePub',project/bookAbbrev,'/OEBPS/content.opf')}" format="xml" indent="yes">
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" version="3.0"  xml:lang="en" unique-identifier="pub-identifier">

<metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:identifier id="pub-identifier">temporary-<xsl:value-of select="/project/bookAbbrev"/>1</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title><xsl:value-of select="/project/bookTitle"/>-v1</dc:title>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <dc:creator id="creator">MDB</dc:creator>
    <dc:subject>history</dc:subject>
    <dc:date>2017-06-26</dc:date>
    <meta name="cover" content="cover-image"/>
    <meta property="dcterms:modified"><xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]Z')"/> </meta>
</metadata>
</package>
</xsl:result-document>
<!-- end content.opf -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've not included the XML file, since I don't think it is needed in this example. I've also removed other result-document sections.

The desired output of this .opf file would be the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
     version="3.0"
     xml:lang="en"
     unique-identifier="pub-identifier">
<metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:identifier" id="pub-identifier">temporary-WB-A1</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title>Christian County Kentucky Will Book A-v1</dc:title>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <dc:creator id="creator">MDB</dc:creator>
    <dc:subject>history</dc:subject>
    <dc:date>2017-06-26</dc:date>
    <meta name="cover" content="cover-image"/>
    <meta property="dcterms:modified">2017-07-17T16:44:57Z</meta>
</metadata>
</package>
```

But instead of the `<metadata>` element holding the **xmlns:dc** namespace declaration, all the children have the **xmlns:dc** declaration and the parent no declaration as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"
     version="3.0"
     xml:lang="en"
     unique-identifier="pub-identifier">
<metadata>
  <dc:identifier xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" id="pub-identifier">temporary-WB-A1</dc:identifier>
  <dc:title xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Christian County Kentucky Will Book A-v1</dc:title>
  <dc:language xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">en</dc:language>
  <dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" id="creator">MDB</dc:creator>
  <dc:subject xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">history</dc:subject>
  <dc:date xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">2017-06-26</dc:date>
  <meta name="cover" content="cover-image"/>
  <meta property="dcterms:modified">2017-07-17T16:44:57Z</meta>
</metadata>
</package>
```

Any help or explanation would be appreciated. I've searched the forum multiple times, but I don't think the solutions I've found in other posts are quite identical to this problem. I hope the info posted in my question is enough to make the problem clear. I'm novice to intermediate with XSL experience so may have used some inappropriate terminology.
Thank you - Michael

Comment: What happens if you remove the `xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"` declaration from the `xsl:stylesheet`element?

Comment: I did try that and got the following error message from the Saxon XSLT 2.0 processor    `Error at xsl:stylesheet on line 9 column 16 of DB-WB-CO-epubText-split.xsl:
  XTSE0808: Namespace prefix dc is not declared
Stylesheet compilation failed: 1 error reported`

Comment: We need to have a small but complete example - preferably one without `xsl:result-document` (and with `xml:template`). -- FWIW, the difference between the output you get and the one you want is purely cosmetic.

Comment: Michael, thanks for commenting. The code I posted is from my working stylesheet. I only deleted all the other result-document sections that created additional files. This particular part only reads a coulple of values from the XML file. I could replace the xsl:value-of calls with set text if that woudl be better. There are no other templates in the stylesheet that are being callled. You may be correct that it doesn't mater, but I'm trying to match the format I'm finding in reference epub3 documents.  Thanks, Michael

Comment: Well, something doesn't fit here, because removing  the `xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"` declaration from the `xsl:stylesheet` element should not produce an error: the declaration is repeated in the `metadata` element, and I don't see that it's being used anywhere outside this scope.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking it is being used in the xsl:result-document where the `<metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">` is located in the XSLT file. The transform completes while the declaration is in the stylesheet. When I remove it, I get the error above `Namespace prefix dc is not declared`.

Comment: It looks like the error may come from not deleting dc in the `exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsl dc epub my"` after deleting the namespace declaration.

Comment: It looks like your suggestion to remove the declaration will solve the problem. It seems my error was not also removing the dc from the exclude-results-prefix afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired output has a namespace declaration on an element where it is not actually needed. That's fine; but to achieve this you need to understand the rules for how namespaces are implicitly added to elements.

The element is constructed using a literal result element. The rule for literal result elements is that they have copies of all the namespaces that are in scope for the LRE in the stylesheet, other than excluded namespaces. In your case dc is an excluded namespace because it appears in the value of the exclude-result-prefixes attribute.

If you want to exclude this namespace for the package element but not for the metadata element, there are several options available:

(a) avoid declaring the namespace at the `xsl:stylesheet` level; declare it only where it is needed

(b) use the `xsl:exclude-result-prefixes` attribute locally on the literal result elements rather than (or as well as) on the `xsl:stylesheet` element. However, this would require a bit of reorganisation of your code, because the value is cumulative: if a prefix is excluded on one stylesheet element, then it is automatically excluded for its children and descendants. You would have to move the construction of the `package` element into a named template so it is not lexically contained within the `metadata` literal result element.

(c) use the `xsl:namespace` instruction to explicitly add the namespace to the `package` element.

(d) construct the `metadata` element using `xsl:element` rather than using an LRE, and then remove 'dc' from the list of excluded result prefixes (`exclude-result-prefixes` applies only to elements created using an LRE).

I think the simplest solution is (a). Unless there are things in your real stylesheet that aren't exposed by this sample, the declaration of the dc namespace at stylesheet level is unnecessary.

Note that none of this has anything to do with the use of `xsl:result-document`.

Comment: Mr. Kay, thank you for the detailed response. I have the result I need now after removing the xmlns:dc declaration as you and Michael suggested. The error after removing must have been from my failure to remove the dc value from the exlude-result-prefixes afterward. Even with the benefit of several of your books, and video series I've watched from Ken Holman and Dimitri Novatchev, I still struggle with the namespace concepts. Thanks, Michael

Comment: Yes, the complexity of namespaces is horrendous (I once famously said that the design was so bad, no-one would ever use them). But actually, once you've grasped the abstraction of namespace nodes in the XDM tree, it's not difficult to understand the rules.